# Still prompted for token authentication, even though it is saved in configuration

Tags: git, github

in the process of cloning a repository from github via the https line I can copy on github, my git command line throws me an error every time.

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
```

However, in my line of reasoning, I already included my token as part of my github credentials. Specifically, I tried two different ways that were presented in similar problems on stackoverflow:

1. Entering my PAT as user-password
2. Entering the PAT as "token" in the [github]-area of my config file

In both cases, the error comes out. I guess there is an easy solution that I am missing, but I seem to be unable to find any more clues. Is it wrong to clone the https-code?

Best,
Tarotis

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the [github] area of your config file", but Git does not have a `[github]` section. You can put in any random section you like, such as `[nasal "effigy"]` or `[infundibulum]`. The format allows it and if nobody looks these up, they just sit there unused. So if you've made a `[github]` section in `.git/config`, Git just cheerfully ignores it.

Comment: The PAT-as-password thing *should* work though. You might need to do some sort of GitHub side settings to give that PAT particular access privileges; I don't know as I don't actually use PATs on GitHub.

Comment: It works on other machines I have, but not on the main one. But I think the problem lays elsewhere: I now manually removed user.name and user.password, as well as github.token, but cloning a private https-repo from github classroom still throws me the authentication password error. The global-config had author/password removed, the system-config is empty. What I would expect is that cloning/pushing would now require me to enter my github name and password, but it doesnt. Could there be something cached that throws the problem?
Edit: The PAT has all possible access privileges.

Comment: On the machine that's not working, perhaps there's an https proxy in the way? Or, you have a cached user-and-password saved somewhere with the wrong things in it? Git doesn't do any user and password stuff. It shoves all that off onto other programs. When using http/https, the "other program" is a configurable *credential helper* (that's the key words to search). There are multiple different credential helpers, each with its own quirks.